# Function to read words reads only every other letter

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, cpu-word, getchar

so I ahve this function that reads from command line and then inserts it into the tree, but it somehow reads only every second letter and not every one and I can't spot the mistake. Can anyone help?

```
char keys[100]={0};
initialize(&trie);
int c, wordnumber=0, letters=0; 

while ((c=getchar()) != EOF )
{ 
    c=getchar();
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        c = toupper(c);
        keys[letters]=c;
        letters++;
    }
    else 
    {
        keys[letters]='\0';
        if(keys[0]!='\0') insert(&trie, keys);
        letters=0;
        wordnumber++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

getchar() gets the next character. You're calling it twice each loop. Once in the condition in the while loop, and then once in the first line in the loop.

Get rid of the first line in the loop (c=getchar()) and it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove

```
c=getchar(); // read a char
```

The reason is that you already read it once by this line:

```
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF ) // read a char and check
```

Answer (score 0):

This! You are using `getchar()` two times! Once in `while loop` and other inside loop.

```
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF )
    { 
        c=getchar();
```